# Find all .php files inside directories with writable permissions

Tags: find, chmod

I'm looking for a linux command to scan through all writable directories on the server and show ones with .php and .html files inside them.

Something like:

```
find -type d -writable -exec find {} -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.html' \;
```

10x!

Comment: What does writable mean? User, Group, All?

Comment: writable by All

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the `-writable` by `-perm`

```
find -type d -perm -a=w  -exec find {} -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.html' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `uniq` together with `sudo`:

`find / -type f -iname '*.php' -execdir sudo -u #UID -- bash -c 'test -w ./ && pwd' ';' |uniq`

Replace UID with a non-existent user id, so `test -w` will only get true from *all* write permission.

Answer (score 0):

with versions of GNU `find` strictly greater than 4.8.0 (not released yet as of 2021-11-08), you can do:

```
find . -type d -perm -a=w -print0 |
  LC_ALL=C find -file0-from - -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    '(' -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.html' ')'
```

<sup>(in the current development version, the second `find` complains if the first one returns nothing which is less than ideal. Let's hope it will be fixed before the release. If not, you could use moreutils `ifne` to work around it)</sup>

`-perm -a=w` selects files for which the `w` bit it set for all of *user*, *group* and *other*, but note that for those directories to be writeable, users still need to be able to get there, so have search access to all the paths components that lead there. Also note that a directory that is not writable by a group that has no member could still be seen as world-writable, but would not be reported here.

`-writable` itself selects files that are writable by the user invoking `find` (using the `access()` system call, so does not only take into accounts the permissions of file itself).

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
for d (**/*(ND/Ff[a+w])) print -rC1 -- $d/*.(#i)(php|html)(ND)
```